# Node.js + ExpressJS + Socket.IO TypeError: obj.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, typeerror

I have unfortunately hit a roadblock in my work. I have a node.js+ExpressJS back end hooked up to a front end via Socket.io and have created the server and client as follows:

app.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
// Routes and io.on statement with listeners on 'connection'
server.listen(2000);
io.listen(2000);
```

Index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--- html stuff --->
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery.min.js></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = new io.Socket('localhost', {port: 2000});
        socket.connect();
        // other js that doesn't get picked up
    });
    </script>
```

What happens when I crack open my console in browser is:

```js
io.connect();
TypeError: obj.on is not a function
```

Did I miss something, or is a stroke of misfortune fall into my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try changing in your index.html:

```
var socket = new io.Socket('localhost', {port: 2000});
socket.connect();
```

to:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

Comment: I'm using a different library, but can confirm that `obj.on is not a function` is due to not using an object created with `new`. Thanks.